# Build package but not found

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When doing `catkin_make` I get:

```
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: C:/Users/Hector/Desktop/Projects/ROSProject/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: C:/opt/ros/melodic/x64;C:/opt/rosdeps/x64;C:/opt/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows
-- This workspace overlays: C:/opt/ros/melodic/x64
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: C:/opt/python27amd64/python.exe
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Using empy: C:/opt/python27amd64/lib/site-packages/em.pyc
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: C:/Users/Hector/Desktop/Projects/ROSProject/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: C:/opt/python27amd64/Scripts/nosetests-2.7.exe
-- catkin 0.7.24
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- beginner_tutorials: 1 messages, 0 services
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Hector/Desktop/Projects/ROSProject/catkin_ws/build
[ 13%] Built target Project__setup_util.py_exec_install_python
[ 13%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 13%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num
[ 20%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp
[ 33%] Built target listener
[ 46%] Built target talker
[ 46%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 53%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_lisp
[ 53%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 60%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 60%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 73%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_eus
[ 73%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 86%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_py
[ 86%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages
[100%] Built target points_and_lines
Base path: C:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Projects\ROSProject\catkin_ws
Source space: C:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Projects\ROSProject\catkin_ws\src
Build space: C:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Projects\ROSProject\catkin_ws\build
Devel space: C:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Projects\ROSProject\catkin_ws\devel
Install space: C:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Projects\ROSProject\catkin_ws\install
####
#### Running command: "cmake C:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Projects\ROSProject\catkin_ws\src -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=C:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Projects\ROSProject\catkin_ws\devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Projects\ROSProject\catkin_ws\install -G NMake Makefiles" in "C:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Projects\ROSProject\catkin_ws\build"
####
####
#### Running command: "nmake" in "C:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Projects\ROSProject\catkin_ws\build"
####
```

But then, if I try `roscd beginner_tutorials` says:

```
[rospack] Error: package 'beginner_tutorials' package not found
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351250/build-package-but-not-found/) by [hect1995](https://answers.ros.org/users/38874/hect1995/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2020-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

solved, I had not source the package

---

Originally posted by [hect1995](https://answers.ros.org/users/38874/hect1995/) with karma: 68 on 2020-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0